# Problema ao concatenar query no PDO

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite,

Eu tenho uma pesquisa que contém múltiplas escolhas por `checkbox` e `Selects` e estou a tentar concatenar a `query` para pesquisa consoante a escolha do utilizador mas dame-me erro não sei o que posso estar a fazer mal vou deixar o código que tenho actualmente para verem e se possivel me dizerem o que posso estar a fazer mal.

**Código**

```
 $result_keywords = "";

    if(isset($_GET['pesquisa'])){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM estabelecimentos WHERE keywords_pesquisa LIKE :keywords_pesquisa OR titulo LIKE :titulo AND activo = :activo ";
        $result_keywords = $conexao->prepare($sql); 

    }

    $checado = implode(",", $_POST['servicos']);
    if(isset($_POST['servicos'])){

        $sql .= "AND servicos = :servicos ";
        $result_keywords = $conexao->prepare($sql); 

    }

    if(isset($_GET['pesquisa'])){

    $result_keywords->bindValue(':activo', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $result_keywords->bindValue(':titulo', "%{$_GET['pesquisa']}%", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $result_keywords->bindValue(':keywords_pesquisa', "%{$_GET['pesquisa']}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    }
    if(isset($_POST['servicos'])){

        $result_keywords->bindValue(':servicos', implode(",", $_POST['servicos']), PDO::PARAM_STR); 

    }
$result_keywords->execute(); 
$row_keywords = $result_keywords->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro? a instrução sql vem montada errada?

Comment: Agora nao da erro mas não apresenta os resultados, a query e bem montada

Comment: Pode colocar uma query aqui nos comentários

Comment: Já consegui por a listar tinha alguns erros de sintaxe só que so da se selecionar uma chekbox se selecionar duas nao me retorna dados

Comment: Para cada cada valor você precisa de um placeholder(`:palceholder`) na consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Falta usar parênteses na query. Tente isto:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM estabelecimentos WHERE keywords_pesquisa LIKE (:keywords_pesquisa)
        OR titulo LIKE (:titulo) AND activo = :activo ";
```

Não se esqueça de verificar se todos os termos de sua pesquisa em `keywords_pesquisa` e   `titulo` estão separados por vírgula.

Comment: parênteses ou aspas ?

Comment: Parênteses! As aspas são "embutidas" pelo PDO.